# simple-kibana dependency cookbook faild

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I am trying to use simple-kibana (https://github.com/jsirex/simple-kibana-cookbook) for which I have written wrapper cookbook. simple-kibana has dependency on ark & runit.

When I run chef on node it fails with following error :

```
================================================================================
    Recipe Compile Error in /var/cache/chef/cookbooks/ark/attributes/default.rb
================================================================================

NoMethodError
-------------
undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass

Cookbook Trace:
---------------
  /var/cache/chef/cookbooks/ark/attributes/default.rb:14:in `from_file'

Relevant File Content:
----------------------
/var/cache/chef/cookbooks/ark/attributes/default.rb:

    7:  else
    8:    default['ark']['tar'] = '/bin/tar'
    9:  end
    10:
    11:  pkgs = %w(libtool autoconf) unless platform_family?('mac_os_x','windows')
    12:  pkgs += %w(unzip rsync make gcc) unless platform_family?('mac_os_x','windows')
    13:  pkgs += %w(autogen) unless platform_family?('rhel', 'fedora', 'mac_os_x', 'suse','windows')
    14>> pkgs += %w(gtar) if platform?('freebsd')
    15:
    16:  default['ark']['package_dependencies'] = pkgs
    17:
```

Can anyone help me to fix this. I am on centos 6.4

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Wow, that's odd.  So, two issues off the bat.

1. It appears that ohai thinks you are on a `freebsd` node, otherwise it wouldn't be evaluating line 14.
2. Unless a default value for pkgs is being set prior to line 11 (and the error says it isn't), then pkgs has no value at lines 13 and 14 unless you're on `mac_os_x` or `windows`, and this attributes file will fail for `rhel`, `fedora`, `suse`, and `freebsd`